# Shortening if, else if, else if ... else using loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I have the following lines of code:

```
$(function(){
$("div").scroll(function() {
    function hpos(id) {
        var pos = $("#" + id).position();
        return pos.top;
    }
    function final(id) {
        $("#header").html($("#" + id).html()),
        $("h1").css("visibility","visible"),
        $("#" + id).css("visibility","hidden");
    }
    if (hpos(5) < 0) {
        final(5);
    }
    else if (hpos(4) < 0) {
        final(4);
    }
    else if (hpos(3) < 0) {
        final(3);
    }
    else if (hpos(2) < 0) {
        final(2);
    }
    else {
        final(1);
    }
});
```

});

Shouldn't I be able to shorten it by using a loop instead of the else if statements? I can't find a way to make the loops work with my position().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be shorter:

```
$.each([5,4,3,2], function(i,v) {
    if( hpos(v) < 0 ) {
        final(v);
        return false;
    } else if( v === 2 ) {
        final(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad they both worked! The `return false` ensures that the loop is terminated. Say for example `hpos(5) < 0` is true, you do not want to continue running the loop after you `final(5)`. You want to jump out of the loop. @AndersClausen?

Answer (score 5):

```
for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    if (hpos(i) < 0) {
        final(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

would something like this work? Not tested by the way

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do lots of else if statements is to use the `case` method.

Comment: But case won't work on greater/lesses statements. It is good for a defined values only.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a while version:
:)

```
var elemId = 5;
while (elemId > 1) {
  if (hpos(elemId) < 0) {
    break;
  }
  elemId--;
}
final(elemId);
```